# Cannot call method 'start' of undefined error using Backbone.history.start() and QUnit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, backbone.js, qunit

I'm currently writing unit tests for my backbone.js application, and I'm having a few problems testing the backbone routes with QUnit.

Unfortuntely, I'm getting the following error when attempting to run the test. It appears to be on the QUnit module setup when I create an instance of my Backbone Router:

`Cannot call method 'start' of undefined`

Here is my code for the test's module setup (called on document ready):

```
var router;

module("Test Router", {
    setup: function () {
        router = new TestRouter();
    },
    teardown: function () {
        router = null;
    }
});
```

And here is code for my router:

```
var TestRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

initialize: function () {
    Backbone.history.start();
},

routes: {
    "!/test-view": "testView",
            "!/test-view-two": "testViewTwo",
    "*actions": "testView"
},

testView: function () {
    //view code here
},

    testViewTwo: function () {
    //view code here
}
```

});

Does anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? The code works as expected outside of the QUnit test.

Comment: You mean this works outside of the test itself?  I didn't think you could call Backbone.history.start() from within the routers initialize function.  According to the docs it needs to be called from outside the Router definition.

Comment: Yep, it works outside of the test itself. I copied the example from a tutorial. Moving the Backbone.history.start(); outside of the initialize solves the problem though! Thanks!

Comment: check [answers in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207822/backbone-history-start-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url Hash modifications changes are tracked when you call `Backbone.history.start()` and it was not designed to be used inside the constructor of router. Please change your code to below and give it a try

```
var router;
module("Test Router", {
    setup: function () {
        router = new TestRouter();
        Backbone.history.start(); 
    },
    teardown: function () {
        router = null;
    }
});
```

#### Router

```
var TestRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
initialize: function () {
},
routes: {
    "!/test-view": "testView",
            "!/test-view-two": "testViewTwo",
    "*actions": "testView"
},

testView: function () {
    //view code here
},
testViewTwo: function () {
    //view code here
}
});
```