# Backbone history start not working

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to start history with backbone however I get the error:

> Cannot call method 'start' of undefined

Here is a link to the full code : http://pastebin.com/pNsYghgE

I have jquery, underscore, and backbone js include before this code so I would imagine this should work based off the documentation.  I am using backbone 0.9.2.  What am I doing wring here?

**EDIT: ANSWER**

I want not creating an instance of my routers so I added this code to before I called Backbone.history.start():

```
//initialize all routes
_(this.modules()).each(function(module, moduleName)
{
    _(module.routers).each(function(router, routerName)
    {
        new router();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Backbone.history` can only be started after one or more routers have been defined with routes:

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-113

You can see here, that the `Backbone.history` object is created when routes are defined. I don't see any routers or routes being defined in the posted code, so I'm guessing that this is the problem.

Comment: I do have routes define, added a pastebin link to the full source code.  I also tested with console.log() that the route were being created before I tried to call history.start() and they are if I am setting them up right.

Comment: Turns out that I was not creating an instance of the router, will update my answer to show want I added

Answer (score 1):

When the line is executed Backbone is still not loaded..

Use the

```
$(function() {
  // ...
});
```

For this part of the code as you have done for other blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It seams okey, can you provide more code, and the part of the html you load jquery, undescore and backbone.

inspect the backbone object before: Backbone.history.start(this.options.historyOptions);

Did you create routers before trying to start the history? (Derick Bailey)